# rules for form object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading on Rails form object creation. It is interesting, but something bothers me on the `include` part. Some tutorials include `ActiveModel`, some include `ActiveModel::Model`, and some even with only `ActiveModel::Validations`.

If we are to just include `ActiveModel` only, is there any pro and cons? After all it will include all `ActiveModel` methods instead of picking individually.

Comment: It's a good practice to only include things you actually use.

Comment: any impact on performance by including the whole Activemodel ?

Comment: Does it even work as expected (`include ActiveModel`)? Never tried it, to be honest.